# Equivalence of sums

Tags: calculus, summation, wavelets

I was hoping someone might be able to help me justify this sum equivalence I ran across in a proof. I'm sure it is something simple but never the less I am confused. I have the following for a function $f$ and operator $P_j$. 
$$
\sum_{j=-J}^{J-1} P_{j+1}f(x) - P_jf(x) = \sum_{j=-J+1}^{J}P_jf(x) - \sum_{j=J}^{J-1} P_j f(x) = P_J f(x) - P_{-J} f(x)
$$
If you plug in say $J = 2, 3$ you can see that the end result is true, with little calculation. I am very confused with the middle statement it seems the first sum is just a re-indexing, but the "improper" sum $\sum_{j=J}^{J-1} P_j f(x)$ is confusing me. If someone could help me justify this equivalance I would be very grateful.

Comment: I also want to note that I realize this is a telescoping sequence, and that the final result is to be expected. I'm really just trying to understand the middle sums.

Comment: It’s a typo: the second summation in the middle expression should run from $-J$ to $J-1$.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too. I just had no other way of being sure.

Comment: Yes, typos in mathematical expressions are always a bit nerve-wracking. Fortunately, this one’s pretty clear: it’s a natural typo, and the third expression pretty well confirms it.

Comment: You’re welcome; my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

The first summation in the middle is really $$\displaystyle \sum_{j=-J}^{J-1} P_{j+1}f(x)$$ which can be written as $$\displaystyle \sum_{j=(-J)+1}^{(J-1)+1} P_{j}f(x)$$  or $$\displaystyle \sum_{j=-J+1}^{J} P_{j}f(x)$$

Comment: This does not answer the OP’s question.

Comment: @ Henry I get the re indexing of the first sum, thank you for the extra input with it, but like I had posted the "improper" sum was my concern. I'm just going to chalk it up to a typo.

Comment: sorry about that - I had read the second sum as a straight transcription and missed the missing $-$ in front the the lower $J$